# Why can't I import an external package into my views.py file?

Tags: python, django, django-views, pip

I'm a beginning Django developer and I'm building my very first Feed reader so that I can display RSS data on my template. To get this to work I use the package called: '*feedparser*'.
And I installed it correctly following the steps: '*pip install feedparser*'.

However an error accurs when I want to import this package into my views.py file: 'import "feedparser" can not be resolved'. Because I'm still a beginner I work with tutorials to understand how I can create a feedreader. The very first step in every case is to install this package and to import it (ofcourse!) only using: import feedparser, unfortunately for me, it raises an error. I don't know how to fix it, I can see by using pip freeze that the package indeed is installed but why can't I import it?

I hope someone can help me out because I have tried everything all day and nothing seems to work or to help.

Views.py (import area):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import AddPostCreateForm
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView, 
    DetailView, 
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)
from .models import Post
import feedparser
```

[image]

Here are my installed packages (in the virtual environment):
[image]

Comment: Have you installed it into your virtual environment?

Comment: @Arandomcoder Yes, I have.. I have added the screenshot to my question. As you can see in the top-left corner, I'm currently inside the virtual environment.